# Grouping using groupby based on certain conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
'Date_Time': ['2010-01-01 12:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:33', 
'2010-04-02 12:01:00', '2010-04-01 07:24:00', '2011-01-01 12:01:00', 
'2011-01-01 01:27:33', '2013-01-01 12:01:00', '2014-01-01 12:01:00', 
'2014-01-01 01:27:33', '2015-01-01 01:27:33', '2016-01-01 01:27:33', 
'2011-01-01 01:28:00'],
'order': [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8],
'sort': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})
```

An would like to get the following columns:

1- `sum_order_total_1` which sums up the values in the column `order` grouped by the column `sort` so in this case for the value `1` from column `sort` for each `ID` and returns `Nans` for zeros form column `sort`

2- `sum_order_total_0` which sums up the values in the column `order` grouped by the column `sort` so in this case for the value `0` from column `sort` for each `ID` and returns `Nans` for oness form column `sort`

3- `count_order_date_1` which sums up the values in column `order` of each `ID` grouped by column `Date_Time` for `1` in column `sort` and returns `Nans` for `0` from column `sort`

4-  `count_order_date_0` which sums up the values in column `order` of each `ID` grouped by column `Date_Time` for `0` in column `sort` and returns `Nans` for `1` from column `sort`

The expected reults should look like that attached photo here: [image]

Comment: And what do you have already tried/researched? Because you can take a look at: `pd.pivot_table`, `pd.groupby` etc..

Comment: I used ```data.groupby(['ID', 'sort'])['order'].transform('sum')``` but it does not work properly. how to use ```pd.pivot_table``` in terms of passing multiple conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `groupby` (and `pd.pivot_table`) is that only provide half of the job. They give you the numbers but not in the format that you want. To finalize the format you can use `apply`.

For the total counts I used:

```
# Retrieve your data, similar as in the groupby query you provided.
data_total = pd.pivot_table(df, values='order', index=['ID'], columns=['sort'], aggfunc=np.sum)
data_total.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Which results in the table:

```
sort  ID     0     1
0      1   6.0  11.0
1      2  15.0   NaN
2      3   NaN   9.0
3      4   3.0   2.0
4      5   5.0   NaN
5      6   8.0   6.0
```

Now using this as an index ('ID' and 0 or 1 for the sort.) We can write a small function that will input the right value:

```
def filter_count(data, row, sort_value):
    """ Select the count that belongs to the correct ID and sort combination.  """
    if row['sort'] == sort_value:
        return data[data['ID'] == row['ID']][sort_value].values[0]
    return np.NaN

# Applying the above function for both sort values 0 and 1.
df['total_0'] = df.apply(lambda row: filter_count(data_total, row, 0), axis=1, result_type='expand')
df['total_1'] = df.apply(lambda row: filter_count(data_total, row, 1), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

This leads to:

```
    ID            Date_Time  order  sort  total_1  total_0
0    1  2010-01-01 12:01:00      2     1     11.0      NaN
1    1  2010-01-01 01:27:33      4     1     11.0      NaN
2    1  2010-04-02 12:01:00      5     1     11.0      NaN
3    1  2010-04-01 07:24:00      6     0      NaN      6.0
4    2  2011-01-01 12:01:00      7     0      NaN     15.0
5    2  2011-01-01 01:27:33      8     0      NaN     15.0
6    3  2013-01-01 12:01:00      9     1      9.0      NaN
7    4  2014-01-01 12:01:00      2     1      2.0      NaN
8    4  2014-01-01 01:27:33      3     0      NaN      3.0
9    5  2015-01-01 01:27:33      5     0      NaN      5.0
10   6  2016-01-01 01:27:33      6     1      6.0      NaN
11   6  2011-01-01 01:28:00      8     0      NaN      8.0
```

Now we can apply the same logic to the date, except that the date also contains information about the hours, minutes and seconds. Which can be filtered out using:

```
# Since we are interesting on a per day bases, we remove the hour/minute/seconds part
df['order_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

Now applying the same trick as above, we create a new pivot table, based on the 'ID' and 'order_day':

```
data_date = pd.pivot_table(df, values='order', index=['ID', 'order_day'], columns=['sort'], aggfunc=np.sum)
data_date.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Which is:

```
sort  ID   order_day     0    1
0      1  2010/01/01   NaN  6.0
1      1  2010/04/01   6.0  NaN
2      1  2010/04/02   NaN  5.0
3      2  2011/01/01  15.0  NaN
4      3  2013/01/01   NaN  9.0
5      4  2014/01/01   3.0  2.0
6      5  2015/01/01   5.0  NaN
7      6  2011/01/01   8.0  NaN
```

Writing a second function to fill in the correct value based on 'ID' and 'date':

```
def filter_date(data, row, sort_value):
    if row['sort'] == sort_value:
        return data[(data['ID'] == row['ID']) & (data['order_day'] == row['order_day'])][sort_value].values[0]
    return np.NaN

# Applying the above function for both sort values 0 and 1.
df['total_1'] = df.apply(lambda row: filter_count(data_total, row, 1), axis=1, result_type='expand')
df['total_0'] = df.apply(lambda row: filter_count(data_total, row, 0), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Now we only have to drop the temporary column 'order_day':

```
df.drop(labels=['order_day'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

And the final answer becomes:

```
    ID            Date_Time  order  sort  total_1  total_0  date_0  date_1
0    1  2010-01-01 12:01:00      2     1     11.0      NaN     NaN     6.0
1    1  2010-01-01 01:27:33      4     1     11.0      NaN     NaN     6.0
2    1  2010-04-02 12:01:00      5     1     11.0      NaN     NaN     5.0
3    1  2010-04-01 07:24:00      6     0      NaN      6.0     6.0     NaN
4    2  2011-01-01 12:01:00      7     0      NaN     15.0    15.0     NaN
5    2  2011-01-01 01:27:33      8     0      NaN     15.0    15.0     NaN
6    3  2013-01-01 12:01:00      9     1      9.0      NaN     NaN     9.0
7    4  2014-01-01 12:01:00      2     1      2.0      NaN     NaN     2.0
8    4  2014-01-01 01:27:33      3     0      NaN      3.0     3.0     NaN
9    5  2015-01-01 01:27:33      5     0      NaN      5.0     5.0     NaN
10   6  2016-01-01 01:27:33      6     1      6.0      NaN     NaN     6.0
11   6  2011-01-01 01:28:00      8     0      NaN      8.0     8.0     NaN
```